# Cassandra unable to repair

Tags: cassandra

I have a 6 node Cassandra cluster and i've tested following scenario
i'm turn off 3 nodes, and on remaining 3 nodes i'm drop the table and re-create it, and after 3 node comes up, i'm unable to do repair, its says

```
[Uzbekistan@Gentoo]: nodetool repair --full
Repair command #2 failed with error Got negative replies from endpoints [ ip's of  nodes that i turned off ]
```

and in the logs from node that i turned off

```
ERROR [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2020-08-21 16:13:12,497 RepairMessageVerbHandler.java:177 - Table with id 6a483210-e395-11ea-8da8-990844948c57 was dropped during prepare phase of repair
```

but why this case happens? and how to fix this? thanks

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided?

Answer (score 1):

You are having schema disagreement between nodes of the cluster. If you run nodetool describecluster, then you will see that. For resolving it restart all the nodes and run nodetool describecluster. If no schema mismatch, then you should be able  to run repair.